# Booting a flat binary from USB

Tags: kernel, boot, usb, grub2

Following along with online resources, I've created a multiboot ELF file, but used `objcopy` to create a "flat" binary or data file. The kernel image is simple, only printing "hello world" to the console. Using QEMU, I can run the flat binary with the command `qemu-system-i386 -kernel /path/to/flat/binary`.

The next step in this progression is to actually boot this kernel from the BIOS screen at startup on my machine. The problem is, I don't know how to make this flat binary a bootable image. So far, the furthest I've gotten is to burn the image onto a USB drive, but as a CDrom, and get to the BIOS screen. The option to boot from USB does not show up as an option, and the system will crash when trying to boot from CD.

I'm still new the concepts of systems programming, and don't really know how to get to the next step of booting my program. Is it necessary to install grub to the USB first, then copy over my flat binary, or is there a method of making the flat binary a bootable image directly, and then burning it to the USB. Any advice, help, or pointers to the right direction would be extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Has your kernel its own code for handling the console display/writing and all the minimal subsystems?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plethora of hardware platforms out there on which you can "boot" software on. Based on your question, I presume you are using a standard PC. On a PC, there are two firmware implementations in use: the legacy BIOS and the more recent (but actually quite old by now) UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface). The firmware is stored in ROM, and is (in short) responsible for initializing the hardware into a runnable state, load some code from mass storage, an start it.

Using the BIOS interface to boot something involves writing some 16-bit real mode code, which shows just how old the BIOS really is. I recommend going the UEFI route. For this you will have to write and compile your code to confirm to the UEFI standard, and place the resulting binary on a suitably formatted USB stick or hard drive.

For more information, see Roderick W. Smith's excellent tutorials on the topic: https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-programming/index.html

Comment: Don't forget to disable secure boot ;) It seems to me that the tutorial would help in creating an "EFI program" though, that would run in EFI context. I'm not certain that it is what the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

if you have an EFI file that points to a suitable kernel,it should boot in uefi mode just fine.